# Sigma notation simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am a math beginner and have following sigma formula to solve:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{3} (2x^n + y)$$

Is the result correct?

$$(2x^1 + y) + (2x^2 + y) + (2x^3 + y) = 2(x^1 + x^2 + x^3) + 3y$$

Comment: You are a math beginner who is doing measure-theory?

Comment: Quite correct, except you might denote $x$ rather than $x^1$.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the future it may be useful to note the rules $\sum b\cdot a_n = b \sum a_n$ (where $b$ is independent of n), and $\sum (a_n + b_n) = \sum a_n + \sum b_n$. But don't fall into the pitfall of thinking that $\left(\sum a_n\right)^k = \sum a^k_n$ (a more discrete instance of the Freshman's dream fallacy) or $\sum a_n b_n = \sum a_n \sum b_n$, those are both fallacious.

I'm not sure why this is under measure theory.

Comment: thank you for your comment. PS: Sorry for making you confused, I was not sure which topic this example belongs to

Comment: nah, don't sweat it. glad you found it useful!